# Why wont LCD screen display characters on boot?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lcd

I made a lcd to display a password cracker using python. When running the script it works perfectly fine but when I try to run the script of boot of the pi there is a split second where it works, then the lcd does not display anything. How do I fix this? (I am not experienced with coding with raspberry pi so the code if from different websites)

Code:

```
import smbus
import time
from random import randint
from RPLCD import *
from RPLCD.i2c import CharLCD

LettersAndSymbols = [
    "A",
    "a",
    "B",
    "b",
    "C",
    "c",
    "D",
    "d",
    "E",
    "e",
    "F",
    "f",
    "G",
    "g",
    "H",
    "h",
    "I",
    "i",
    "J",
    "j",
    "K",
    "k",
    "L",
    "l",
    "M",
    "m",
    "N",
    "n",
    "O",
    "o",
    "P",
    "p",
    "Q",
    "q",
    "R",
    "r",
    "S",
    "s",
    "T",
    "t",
    "U",
    "u",
    "V",
    "v",
    "W",
    "w",
    "X",
    "x",
    "Y",
    "y",
    "Z",
    "z",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "0",
]

num = 0

c = 3
n=0
reset = True

GuessAll = ""

framebuffer = [
'',
'',
]

abc = CharLCD('PCF8574', 0x27)

I2C_ADDR  = 0x27
LCD_WIDTH = 16


LCD_CHR = 1
LCD_CMD = 0

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0
LCD_LINE_3 = 0x94
LCD_LINE_4 = 0xD4

LCD_BACKLIGHT  = 0x08  

ENABLE = 0b00000100



E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

def lcd_init():
 
  lcd_byte(0x33,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x32,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x06,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x0C,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x28,LCD_CMD)
  lcd_byte(0x01,LCD_CMD)
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_byte(bits, mode):


  bits_high = mode | (bits & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT
  bits_low = mode | ((bits<<4) & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT

  bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_high)
  lcd_toggle_enable(bits_high)

  bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_low)
  lcd_toggle_enable(bits_low)

def lcd_toggle_enable(bits):
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)
  bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, (bits | ENABLE))
  time.sleep(E_PULSE)
  bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR,(bits & ~ENABLE))
  time.sleep(E_DELAY)

def lcd_string(message,line):

  message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH," ")

  lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

  for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
    lcd_byte(ord(message[i]),LCD_CHR)

def write_to_lcd(lcd, framebuffer, num_cols):
    abc.home()
    for row in framebuffer:
        abc.write_string(row.ljust(num_cols)[:num_cols])
        abc.write_string('\r\n')
       
def long_text(text):
    if len(text)<20:
        abc.write_string(text)
    for i in range(len(text) -20 + 1):
        framebuffer[1] = text[i:i+20]
        write_to_lcd(abc, framebuffer, 20)
        time.sleep(0.2)

while True:
    def main():

      lcd_init()
     
      lcd_string("> Enter Your   <",LCD_LINE_1)
      lcd_string(">  Password    <",LCD_LINE_2)
     
      ClientPassword = input("Please enter a password to test\n")
      startTime = time.time()
      lcd_string(">  Hacking...  <",LCD_LINE_1)
      lcd_string(">              <",LCD_LINE_2)
     
      list1 = [ClientPassword[i:i+c] for i in range(0, len(ClientPassword), c)]
      e = len(list1)
     
      list2 = [ClientPassword[i:i+12] for i in range(0, len(ClientPassword), 12)]
     
      GuessAll = ""
      while GuessAll != ClientPassword:
        for Part in list1:
            GuessPart = ""
            while GuessPart != Part:
                GuessPart = ""
                for i in range(len(Part)):
                    GuessLetter = LettersAndSymbols[randint(0, len(LettersAndSymbols)-1)]
                    GuessPart += GuessLetter
            GuessAll += GuessPart
        executionTime = (time.time() - startTime)
        executionTime = round(executionTime, 1)
       
        print("Cracked password in",round(executionTime, 1),"second(s)! \nPassword was:","".join(list1),"\n")
        list1="".join([str(o) for a,o in enumerate(list1)])
       
        lcd_string(">    Done!     <",LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string(">              <",LCD_LINE_2)
       
        time.sleep(3)
       
        lcd_string(">    Time:     <",LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string(">     "+str(executionTime)+"      <",LCD_LINE_2)
       
        time.sleep(3)
        lcd_string("                ",LCD_LINE_2)
        lcd_string(">  Password:   <",LCD_LINE_1)
        abc.cursor_pos = (1,0)
        long_text(list1)
       
        time.sleep(5)
       

    if __name__ == '__main__':

      try:
        main()
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
      finally:
        lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)
```

I have tried different ways of booting up the pi and starting the script, currently I am going into crontab -e and putting @reboot python3 /home/pi/Code.py &